# Работа с устройством без драйверов под Linux

Tags: linux, драйвер

Суть проблемы: имеется специфическое оборудование которое программируется утилитой производителя, данная утилита работает только под windows. Получилось запустить ее через вайн - вроде пашет, но соединится с устройством и залить прошивку никак ибо нужен драйвер,а он только под windows. Что вообще делают в такой ситуации ? Ставят windows в ВМ и работают от туда ? Этож не удобно то как)).

Comment: Да, в таких безвыходных ситуациях виртуальная машина - это проще, чем 2-я/3-я... реальная ОС. Виртуалку можно всегда легко перенести на другое железо/ОС, хотя бы в этом плюс.

Comment: А если нужны специфичные инструкции процессора или недокументированная фича какого-нибудь COM-порта, которая НЕ реализована в каком-нибудь virtualbox?

Comment: Нормуль так мотаться из одной ОС в другую во время разработки, просто офигенный воркфлоу. Системы сборки, автоматическое тестирование, непрерывная интеграция, континиус деливери и... дуалбут.

Comment: @iDarkLord, ок, какие твои соображения, если внутри виртуалки это не заработает? Напишешь "windows-driver2linux-driver_converter"? Или напишешь после реверс-инженеригна свой драйвер под свежую версию ядра линукса? P.S. Кажись ты не там коментарий оставил.

Comment: Ды были бы src модно было бы позагоняться с портированием виндового дрв под линукс. Кроме того я думаю под виртуалкой почти все заработает, за исключением чисто аппаратных интерфейсов типо PCI-e и всяких системных штук.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого делают `dualboot` - на железо рядом ставят 2 (или больше) операционки. Для специфичного софта используется та ОС под которую этот софт заточен. Интернет смотреть можно под чем угодно, а вот свежий `AutoCAD` или `Adobe Premiere` лучше запускать без всяких прослоек и виртуалок, чтобы не было вот таких постов. Если интерес чисто академический - то можно и поковырять. А если хочется `just work` - делай как советует производитель.

Ещё можно написать разработчикам решения и спросить про поддержку других ОС\аппаратных платформ. Но как показывает практика - это бесполезно, если ты (или фирма) не готов за это заплатить.